# Exit immigration for Argentina-Chile border crossing

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, argentina

So I entered Argentina by plane a month ago, passed the entry immigration checks at the airport, and then some days later took a bus to Chile. The bus went through the Los Libertadores pass, where I passed the Chilean entry immigration procedures and got the PDI paper. However, I do not remember doing anything related to exit immigration from Argentina.

Did I miss something? Should I somehow notify the Argentinian authorities that I left the country? Could there be problems related to this, if/when I visit Argentina next time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The immigration process of exiting Argentina and entering Chile are unified at this crossing. When you complete entry formalities for Chile, Argentina automatically processes your departure. You do not need to see any immigration officer of Argentina when departing.

See:

https://www.unidiversidad.com.ar/paso-a-chile-desde-este-viernes-vuelven-los-controles-unificados-para-turistas

Comment: Nice.  I did a ferry crossing from Argentina to Uruguay and had to do both exit and entry . Apparently it works better with Chile

Comment: @Hilmar Well, a sea port is not like a land border. When you arrive in a Uruguayan port, they can't know you've arrived from Argentina, and if they turn you back for any reason, nobody can guarantee that you go back to Argentina.

Comment: @ach: Not true in this case.  This was the Buenos Aires to Colonia Ferry and  that's the only route they serve from this  from that Terminal in Buenos Aires. In fact, Uruguay entry immigration is done in the Ferry Terminal in Buenos Aires.  Argentina exit and Uruguay entry are in the same room, you just go from one desk to the next.  From Colonia, I think, all ferries got to Buenos Aires.

Comment: @Hilmar, ah ok. In this case, it works the same as it was at Los Libertadores when I crossed it before the tunnel was built - in 2011 (towards Chile) and 2013 (towards Argentina). Every time there was one building where both exit and entry formalities were done. Only IIRC it was on the side of country to which one was entering, on Chilean side quite far from the border line. So now it seems they simplified it even more.